# Setting up testing in Laravel project using Hyn/multi-tenant

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, multi-tenant, laravel-7

I am using the `Hyn/multi-tenant 5.6` package for multi tenant application support.
My application is working fine, I can create tenants and they are running propperly.

The problem comes with testing. I want to setup an **existing tenant** for my testing purpose. But somehow the application can't create the correct routes during testing.
In CreateApplication.php I'm setting the tenant used for testing. Which has `website_id = 1`

```
trait CreatesApplication
{
    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }

    public function setUp() : void{

        parent::setUp();

        $hostname = Hostname::find(1);
        $website = Website::findOrFail($hostname->website_id);
        $tenancy = app(Environment::class);
        $tenancy->hostname($hostname);

        Artisan::call('optimize:clear');
        Artisan::call('tenancy:migrate:fresh', ['--website_id' => 1]);
        Artisan::call('tenancy:db:seed',['--class' => 'TenantSeeder','--website_id' => 1]);

    }

}
```

I found some similar problems by googling but none of their solutions worked for me:
https://github.com/tenancy/multi-tenant/issues/584

All my routes are in my `tenants.php` file and working.
I am using the latest version of PHPUNIT.

**The error I get is:**

`Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException : Route [new_anmeldung_single] not defined.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was writing this question, I tried some more options, added and removed some code (I at least did 10h of it the last week) and to my surprise I found the solution.

I simply forgot to do:

`$tenancy->tenant($website); // switches the tenant and reconfigures the app`
`(new RouteProvider(app()))->boot();//reloads the routes`

So if you want to setup an existing tenant for your testing you will need to add the following piece of code into your setUp() method. If you want to create a new tenant you can follow the example in the issue posted in the question.

```
public function setUp() : void{

        parent::setUp();


        $hostname = Hostname::find(1);
        $website = Website::findOrFail($hostname->website_id);
        $tenancy = app(Environment::class);
        $tenancy->hostname($hostname);
        $tenancy->tenant($website); // switches the tenant and reconfigures the app

        (new RouteProvider(app()))->boot();

        Artisan::call('tenancy:migrate:fresh', ['--website_id' => 1]);
        Artisan::call('tenancy:db:seed',['--class' => 'TenantSeeder','--website_id' => 1]);

    }
```

Sadly this part is not documented, so I hope that someone with similar problems will find this post.